# Ruby: blocks and yield

Tags: ruby, class, yield, block

I run into this exercise about using **blocks** e then calling them with **yield**. It looks like this:

```
class Hero
  def initialize(*names)
    @names = names
  end
  def full_name
    # a hero class allows us to easily combine an arbitrary number of names
    # this is where yield should be
  end
end

def names
  heroes = [Hero.new("Christopher", "Alexander"),
            Hero.new("John", "McCarthy"),
            Hero.new("Emperor", "Joshua", "Abraham", "Norton")]
  # I have to use #map and #join to unify names of a single hero
end
```

Return value should look like this:

```
["Christopher Alexander", "John McCarthy", "Emperor Joshua Abraham Norton"]
```

I know how to use generally blocks and yield. I did very simple exercises before this but I can't solve this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a strange request, but if you have to use yield and join as you write in the comments this is the solution:

```
class Hero
  def initialize(*names)
    @names = names
  end
  def full_name
    if block_given?
      yield @names
    else
      @names.join(' ')
    end
  end
end

def names
  heroes = [Hero.new("Christopher", "Alexander"),
            Hero.new("John", "McCarthy"),
            Hero.new("Emperor", "Joshua", "Abraham", "Norton")]
  heroes.map { |h| h.full_name { |name| name.join(' ') } }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array#join](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Array#join-instance_method). You don't need `yield` or any fancy stuff.

Comment: Each element in heroes is an object. It's not an array so I can't use join: undefined method `join' for #

Comment: `Array#join` is a convention for writing 'instance method `join` of the class `Array`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am kind of a newbie in ruby. 
Join is a method for Array class. But heroes is made of instances of Hero class and I am not getting how to join them since they are not arrays.

Comment: As the request states it's an exercise about blocks and yields. It makes no sense, but he has to provide a solution as required by the exercise.